# how to add file path in django project

Tags: python, django

I am making an online judge in Django. I am taking user code in a file and then compile it and running it and giving the verdict. for example let say a user submitted code in c++ language so I am taking that code in a .cpp file and compile it and running it and I am doing it by giving the absolute path of my .cpp file like E:\online_judge_project\oj\language\forcpp.cpp

my problem is that when I will deploy my project it will cause error because this paths are my local machine path and I can't use that in deployment so how will I access the files( like .cpp file) after the deployment. Although those files are in my project directory only and I kept them in a folder name **language**. my project directory structure is like:

[image]

I am thinking of using **os.join.path()** but I am not getting how to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**did you consider putting your cpp file inside static files and define STATIC_URL and STATICFILES_DIRS in your setting.py**

you can put in the function you are using cpp file

```
import os
print(os.getcwd())
```

this script to know exact location of your script and put cpp file in the same path then you should can access it

Comment: actually No can we do that like static files are the .css, .js files right ???

Comment: i edited the answer, you can do 'os.getcwd())' this return the function's script path then if you put cpp file inside the same path you should access it